# yii 1.1 datepicker's language

Tags: yii, datepicker, internationalization

I'm using (CJui)datepicker in a view, and a skin for it, with default language setted to "it". If I render my view with standard render function, it works well, with the complete layout. If I render my view with `renderPartial("viewName",$data,false,true)` the language is setted to japanese. Why??? (the other params of skin remain correct instead)

PS: Analysing the output code, I noticed that in the case of renderPartial method the javascript function that set default options for datepicker isn't encapsulated in the `jQuery(function($) { ... })` method...

EDIT: the view in question is the admin view generated with Gii module, I noticed that for datepickers into advanced search no parameters of skin work!!

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you have to register your locale(s) in your partially rendered view.

For the simple solving try following:

Before renderPartial add the following code:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->scriptMap['jquery.js'] = false;
```

(or another `.js` file you use for the datepicker).

You could also repair it manually. Open the **jquery-ui-i18n.min.js** localization file or get it from jquery-ui website.

For example, French instance would looks following:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('frDatepicker.js', "
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.datepicker.regional['fr']={
                closeText:'Fermer',prevText:'Précédent',nextText:'Suivant',currentText:'Aujourd\'hui',
                monthNames:['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
                        'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
                monthNamesShort:['Janv.','Févr.','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
                        'Juil.','Août','Sept.','Oct.','Nov.','Déc.'],
                dayNames:['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
                dayNamesShort:['Dim.','Lun.','Mar.','Mer.','Jeu.','Ven.','Sam.'],
                dayNamesMin:['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
                weekHeader:'Sem.',dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy',firstDay:1,isRTL:false,
                showMonthAfterYear:false,yearSuffix:''};
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
});
", CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

Comment: If I add the first line of code before renderPartial, nothing works... I'd like to know if there is a solution to configure yii properly, without add code manually. The other params of the skin work well in the partially rendered view :-/

Comment: No, but in the output code there is already the javascript code that initialize the language of datepicker:
`jQuery.datepicker.setDefaults({'changeMonth':true,'changeYear':true,'maxDate':'0','altFormat':'dd/mm/yy','yearRange':'1900:c','showButtonPanel':true});
jQuery('#Attivita_dataCreazione').datepicker(jQuery.extend({showMonthAfterYear:false},jQuery.datepicker.regional['it'],[]));
jQuery('#Attivita_dataModifica').datepicker(jQuery.extend({showMonthAfterYear:false},jQuery.datepicker.regional['it'],[]));`
the trouble is that it isn't encapsulated in the `jQuery(function($) { ... })` method